# Are Newton's equations accurate on Earth when we ignore fictitious forces?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, reference-frames, inertial-frames, centrifugal-force

I am a high school student and I just got to know about inertial and non-inertial frames of reference. And since the earth is actually accelerating  around the sun, and the sun is also accelerating, can we use Newton's equations accurately?

Comment: Have you tried calculating Earth’s acceleration, compared to, say, $g$?

Comment: No I meant that the Earth is accelerating around the sun and the sun is also accelerating. So shouldn't that affect calculations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to this question depends on the analysis being done.  Sometimes we are more sensitive to the non-inertial effects of the Earth than others.

Fundamentally you are correct that our day to day existence on the surface of the Earth is in a non-inertial frame.  There are centripetal, Coriolis, and even Euler effects to consider.  However, for most situations, we can ignore these effects.  The best way to understand this is to look at a few examples of situations that do or do not need non-inertial equations of motion to accurately predict.

A sniper rifle bullet traveling a mile or more does indeed exhibit measurable non-inertial effects.  A bullet may deviate over these distances by 1 inch or so due to Coriolis effects.  Sniper calculators actually account for this, as do the calculators used in artillery.

Obviously orbiting bodies like the ISS can only be understood by properly accounting for rotation in the equations of motion.  Typically we do calculations for them in an Earth-centered inertial (ECI) frame, which is a non-rotating coordinate system to avoid having to account for the non-inertial effects directly.

On the other hand, planes are typically well modeled as flying in an inertial environment, even if the planet is rotating.  In general, the errors caused by wind and the corrections by guidance algorithms are orders of magnitude larger than the non-inertial effects.

For most day-to-day existence and most experiments, we can ignore the non-inertial effects.  They fall far short of the measurement errors that occur.  However, it is possible to construct experiments which are intentionally designed to demonstrate the non-inertial nature of the rotating planet.  These experiments, such as the [Foucault pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foucault_pendulum), are designed around very massive predictable objects whose motion extends for long periods of time.

For only the most exotic of problems do we note that even the ECI frame is not inertial, as we are technically rotating around the sun.  There are indeed astronomical problems which are done in the [ICRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Celestial_Reference_System) because a more inertial frame is needed.  I am personally not aware of any work that calls for recognizing that the solar system is revolving around the galactic center, but one may exist (you could ask on SpaceExploration.SE)

Comment: As a side note, when considering the effect of rotation around the galactic center: On those sorts of time scales, the motion of the planets is actually chaotic and not predictable.  This limits the value of including such non-inertial corrections.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I wanted to understand.

Comment: One big example where you cannot ignore earth rotation is meteorology (wind trajectories curve due to coriolis)

Comment: Nice answer. +1 from me.